# How to Make admin Sidebar Menu always be Collapse by code

Tags: user-meta, buttons

I have solution with js that click on the Collapse button, but this is no good solution. I want to make this work true DB with php code.

I found that the table who hold this value is [`wp_usermeta`](http://s1.postimg.org/zdmhvf15b/image.jpg). Then there is a column [`meta_key`] that hold: `user-settings` and there is column  `meta_value` that hold values for example: [`mfold=o&editor=tinymce&libraryContent=browse&ed_size=465`](http://s11.postimg.org/s89mgyobn/dbb.jpg).

The value that I need is `mfold=o` so I want to check

```
if "mfold" not exsist then add mfold=1, else check if mfold=o update to mfold=1
```

I've tried to play with

```
<?php get_user_meta($user_id, $key, $single);  ?>
```

and

```
<?php update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value ); ?>
```

but without luck

Comment: Two request, this is not your first question, please work on your formatting so that others don't have to clean your mess. Also, please revisit **all** your previous questions, and accept answers where appropriate, otherwise leave constructive feedback if necessary. Please see [help] and visit the [tour] page to learn how this site operates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the admin sidebar menu always be collapsed, try adding the following code in the `functions.php` file of your [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), or add it in your site using a plugin like [Code Snippets](http://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/), or [Add Actions and Filters](http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-actions-and-filters/).

```
global $user_ID;
$user_fold = get_user_meta( $user_ID, 'wp_user-settings', true );
$exp_array = explode( "&", $user_fold );
$search_array = array_search( "mfold=o", $exp_array );
if ( $search_array ) {
    $exp_array[ $search_array ] = "mfold=f";
    $exp_array = implode( "&", $exp_array );
    update_user_meta( $user_ID, 'wp_user-settings', $exp_array );
}
```